# For each duplicate in array, find the index of the first duplicate

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

I have a form where users can add "rows" of items. Let's say each row has a "name" and "slug". The output of this is an array of objects, like so:

```
[
 {
 "name": "Bananas",
 "slug": "bananas"
},{
 "name": "Bananas",
 "slug": "bananas"
},{
 "name": "Silver Spoons",
 "slug": "silver_spoons"
},{
 "name": "Silver Spoons",
 "slug": "silver_spoons"
}
]
```

Now, given a user enters this. **I want to find, for each duplicate `'slug'`, the index of its first occurence**, so that I can show a validation-error on that row. I understand I can easily `_.pluck` the ids out, but I'm still not sure what the best approach after that would be. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on Margus' answer, you could do something like this:

Loop through the array storing the index of the first occurrence of slug in a hashmap.

Then if you come across another occurrence of the same slug, add the index of the first occurrence to an array.

```
function getFirstOccurences(arr) {
    var items = {};
    var alreadyExist = [];
    arr.forEach(function(item, index) {
        if(items.hasOwnProperty(item.slug)) {
            alreadyExist.push(items[item.slug]);
        }
        else {
            items[item.slug] = index;
        }
    });
    return alreadyExist;
}
```

Edit: fixed check for existing item and added [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/qyx4o5fh/)

Comment: Thanks, worked a treat. Specs changed so I now have to show errors on all duplicates except the first one (sigh). Modified a bit to use underscore's `_.each` (which they claim is faster in latest version), and to allow key to be entered as param. Result here: http://jsbin.com/qunabinagiqu/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery **inArray**

```
var items = [
    {
     "name": "Bananas",
     "slug": "bananas"
    },{
     "name": "Bananas",
     "slug": "bananas"
    },{
     "name": "Silver Spoons",
     "slug": "silver_spoons"
    },{
     "name": "Silver Spoons",
     "slug": "silver_spoons"
    }
]; 
var names = [];
var duplicates = [];
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++ ) {
    var value = items[i].name;
    if ($.inArray(value, names) > -1) {
        duplicates.push(i);
    } else {
        names.push(value);
    }
}
alert(names.toString());
alert(duplicates.toString());
```

Example : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/margusmartsepp/dx7xg0uq/2/)

Comment: I'm not quite sure how that would get me the results I'm looking for. What I'd expect here is an array of indices of the first duplicates. So in the above examples, I'd expect [0, 2]. Can you elaborate maybe how this would help me get there?

Comment: Note that this will queue up all duplicate indexes.